How can I search (not filter) for records in Redpanda Console/Kowl
I want to be able to search for a given key inside a topic via Redpanda Console.
However, I think all it does is get the max messages (500) and then do the filter on it (javascript and inline), not really search the topic/partitions for the filter.
In this github issue, it seems that it's possible:

Hi, the max results filter is always after filters. What you want to
achieve is a common usecase, and to do so you just need to adapt the
"Start offset" to something like "oldest" or use a timestamp from
where you want to start consuming forwards. You can abort the search
whenever you want then. The filter is evaluated in the backend, hence
this is very fast too.

but even if I set "Beginning"( assuming it's the same as oldest) in the later versions (2.7x) I can't get to search, but only filter on the 500 messages that I can get either from beginning/newest or starting offset.
Is it (was it ever) possible to search for a key value from the beginning of a topic/partition for a key/header/value etc criteria with Kowl/Redpanda Console?

Short answer is no. Kafka/Redpanda are not KV stores. They are logs... You filter logs with a search. Any UI tool is just a fancy version of kafka-console-consumer --topic T | grep "event"
You should instead look into something like Redpanda Connect, paired with Redis or Elasticsearch/Graylog.

Maybe I misworded my question a bit. For Kowl/Redpanda UI and even OffsetExplorer, the UI is built to first get the records in memory and THEN filter. However, that can lead to huge memory spikes for me and not get all results anyway. Isn't there an option in a UI that consumes the topic from the beginning looking for something and discarding unmatched records instead of storing them in memory.

Sounds like a bug in those apps. I personally don't use them, but there is no need to store un-matched records in memory. The match can be applied while consuming, and the rest can be discarded... I suggest you file issues with the developers. That being said, grep would be better, and do what you want.

Yes, I suspected it might be a bug in current versions, looking for a one where it worked - devs demand it is not...

Conduktor UI is another option that I've seen coworkers use for searching in topics
